# undocumented PostGIS ST_Distance function taking text as parameters

Tags: postgis

It seems that I have a variant of `ST_Distance` function in my PostGIS (3.2.1) that is not on [the documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.st_distance(text, text)                                     
  RETURNS double precision                                                                     
  LANGUAGE sql                                                                                 
  IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT                                                               
 AS $function$ SELECT public.ST_Distance($1::public.geometry, $2::public.geometry);  $function$
 ;
```

So, `\df` returns:

```
=> \df st_distance
                                                  List of functions
 Schema |    Name     | Result data type |                         Argument data types                         | Type 
--------+-------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------
 public | st_distance | double precision | geog1 geography, geog2 geography, use_spheroid boolean DEFAULT true | func
 public | st_distance | double precision | geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry                                      | func
 public | st_distance | double precision | text, text                                                          | func
(3 rows)
```

I don't remember defining that function (the third variant) myself.

By comparison, `ST_Hausdorffdistance` does not have the text version.

```
=> \df st_hausdorffdistance
                                             List of functions
 Schema |         Name         | Result data type |               Argument data types                | Type 
--------+----------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+------
 public | st_hausdorffdistance | double precision | geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry                   | func
 public | st_hausdorffdistance | double precision | geom1 geometry, geom2 geometry, double precision | func
(2 rows)
```

*Could anyone confirm whether if it's defined by PostGIS and what purpose does it serve?*

**-- Clarification --**

The reason I am asking is that I have defined a type that automatically converts to both the `geometry` and `text` types. And the fact that `ST_Distance` accepts both types *seems* to be causing an ambiguity, although it was intended in 1.5 to avoid ambiguity per the source code in the answer.

Comment: Just to add context: PostgreSQL has a [sequenced try-and-error best-or-first methodology](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) to identify an appropriate function signature for given arguments. Without that 'hack', or the newer **implicit** `CAST(TEXT AS GEOMETRY)`, any `unknown` arguments will raise an ambiguity error. All functions **with a signature for `GEOGRAPHY`** that were present in PostGIS < 2.0 have these additional signatures!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `ST_Distance(text, text)` is defined by PostGIS. Here's the source code:

```
-- Availability: 1.5.0 - this is just a hack to prevent unknown from causing ambiguous name because of geography
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_Distance(text, text)
    RETURNS float8 AS
    $$ SELECT @extschema@.ST_Distance($1::@extschema@.geometry, $2::@extschema@.geometry);  $$
    LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE;
```

This may no longer be needed, now that text automatically casts to `geometry`.

Answer (score 2):

Very short, but you should be able to understand it:

```
postgres=# SELECT ST_Distance('POINT(0 0)','POINT(1 1)');
    st_distance     
--------------------
 1.4142135623730951
(1 row)
```

or more explicitly:

```
postgres=# SELECT ST_Distance('POINT(0 0)'::text,'POINT(1 1)'::text);
    st_distance     
--------------------
 1.4142135623730951
(1 row)
```

vs

```
postgres=# SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Point(0,0), ST_Point(1,1));
    st_distance     
--------------------
 1.4142135623730951
(1 row)
```

Please note that:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof('Point(0 0)'::text);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 text
(1 row)
```

and:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_typeof('Point(0 0)'::geometry);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 geometry
(1 row)
```

See "Table 9.70. System Catalog Information Functions" here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-info.html
fore more information on the `pg_typeof()` function, which, at the time of writing, tells:

> pg_typeof ( "any" ) → regtype
>
> Returns the OID of the data type of the value that is passed to it.
> This can be helpful for troubleshooting or dynamically constructing
> SQL queries. The function is declared as returning regtype, which is
> an OID alias type (see Section 8.19); this means that it is the same
> as an OID for comparison purposes but displays as a type name.
>
> For example:
>
> `SELECT pg_typeof(33);  pg_typeof`
> `-----------`
> `integer`
>
> `SELECT typlen FROM pg_type WHERE oid = pg_typeof(33);  typlen`
> `--------`
> `4`